# Can't understand the meaning of "have taken" in context

Tags: meaning

- What changes **have taken** place in your province?

Can anyone tell me what **"have taken"** means in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing the sentence wrongly. To "take place" means to happen or occur. It is a 'phrase of place'.

As [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take-place) says,

> When something takes place, it happens, especially in a controlled or organized way

Its examples make the meaning clear:

```
The discussion took place in a famous villa on the lake's shore.
She wanted Hugh's wedding to take place quickly.
Elections will now take place on November the twenty-fifth.
```

So your sentence asks,

> 'What changes have occurred in your province?'